# Interface with multiple types

Tags: typescript

I have a `interface` property:

```
LegalReviewDate?: string | Date;
```

When upload to a SharePoint list, it needs to be a `Date` object.  I know it will be a string until I submit it, so I try this:

```
contract.LegalReviewDate = new Date(contract.LegalReviewDate);
```

But that throws an error because it is not a  `string` or `number` (the function thinks it could be a `Date` which is invalid).

Is there a way to tell the function `new Date` that it is a string?

Comment: `new Date(contract.LegalReviewDate as string)`?

Comment: You could use a type guard and make it into a date if it's a string

Comment: How do you know that it's a `string` and not a `Date`?  Did you assign a `string` to it?  If so, can we see that code?

Comment: @jcalz Through the entire project except for uploadin, the property is a string.  I use a Office Fabric UI `DatePicker` which returns a `Date` that I convert to a string.  At time of upload, I need it to be a `Date`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That works, thank you.  If you want to, submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You should probably use two properties and not one, or two objects, one of which has a `string` property and another that you use to upload that has a `Date` property.  Reusing the same property for different types that changes back and forth is hard to make type-safe.  If you want to use an assertion like `as string` to make the error go away, that will work, but I'd be inclined to refactor so it isn't necessary.  Good luck!

Comment: I would go with @jcalz' advice. They have much more experience and expertise in TypeScript than I do. I know enough to get me into trouble :).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this.

If you are absolutely sure that at the moment the code runs, the value of `contract.LegalReviewDate` is a string with a date formatted appropriately (see [this answer by CMS to Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/215552) for more information on cross-browser supported formats), you can use the `as` operator to tell TypeScript you are confident of its validity:

```
contract.LegalReviewDate = new Date(contract.LegalReviewDate as string);
```

You can also use type guards to make sure that your assumptions are correct:

```
if (typeof contract.LegalReviewDate === 'string') {
    contract.LegalReviewDate = new Date(contract.LegalReviewDate as string);
}
if (typeof contract.LegalReviewDate === 'object' && contract.LegalReviewDate instanceof Date) {
    contract.LegalReviewDate = contract.LegalReviewDate as Date;
    // OR contract.LegalReviewDate = new Date(contract.LegalReviewDate.valueOf());
}
```

Or as @jcalz mentions, use two separate properties or objects. For instance,

```
interface Contract {
    LegalReviewDate?: string;
}

interface ContractDTO {
    LegalReviewDate?: Date;
}
```

Then, create a new `ContractDTO` that you use to pass data to (and from) SharePoint.